# My wireless/WiFi connection does not work

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking, broadcom, lenovo

my wireless isn't working since 14.04 on my Lenovo Ideapad N581.
I can see the Network, but cannot connect to it.

I can only connect to the network, when I switch the mode from 802.11bgn to 802.11abg. So I conclude that the n protocol is the problem.

But since I cannot change the mode of any other network then my own, this remains a big problem.

I run the script as told in [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos).

You can find the result here: [script result](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/8559279/).

I also tried to install the linux-firmware and linux-firmware-nonfree. But everything's still the same.

So can anyone pls help me? I really need a working wireless :)

Comment: Have you tried to install the proprietary Broadcom driver? (bcmwl)

Comment: I tried, but wasn't helping.
Wild Man solved my problem. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Then reboot and let ubuntu load the `brcmsmac` driver if it does not load then you will need to remove `brcmsmac` and `bcma` driver's from the blacklist file like so:

```
sudo sed 's/blacklist brcmsmac//' -i /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
sudo sed 's/blacklist bcma//' -i /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Then blacklist the b43 and ssb driver:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist b43" >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
echo "blacklist ssb" >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

exit
Reboot

Comment: Thanks! It worked :) At least with my home network. Will try it soon with other networks (university, work).